# Critical points of a strictly subharmonic function

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, riemannian-geometry, elliptic-pde, harmonic-functions, geometric-analysis

Let $M$ be a smooth, compact manifold with boundary. Let $u: M \to \mathbf{R}$ be a smooth function that has its Riemannian Laplacian equal to a positive constant:
\begin{equation}
\Delta u = A > 0.
\end{equation}
Moreover,
\begin{equation}
0 < u \leq 1  \text{ on $M$} \quad \text{and} \quad u \equiv 1 \text{ on $\partial M$}. 
\end{equation}

Continuity forces $u$ to attain its infimum somewhere in the interior of $M$.

> Can $u$ have any other critical values? Is the critical set $\lvert \nabla u \rvert^{-1}(\{ 0 \})$ connected?

Comment: I would guess that if your manifold with boundary is two Euclidean balls joined by a thin neck, then the critical set has a least three critical points.  There might be some hope for proving what you want for convex domains using ideas such as in [this](http://web.math.unifi.it/users/colesant/didattica/AARMS/sources/Korevaar.pdf) paper of Korevaar.

Comment: @RBega2 That's very cool, thanks for the suggestion! I haven't yet figured out whether I can solve my problem using the article, but I think I should be able to exclude thin necks, so perhaps there's a chance.